# Regex Evaluating Matches Incorrectly

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble getting a Java flavored Regular expression to evaluate a match correctly. I define the following regular expressions:

```
//Any digit
static String NUM = "[0-9]";

//Exponent with only 3 digits specified
static String EXPONENT = "([Ee][+-]?" + NUM + "(" + NUM + "(" + NUM + ")?)?)";

static String NUMBER = "([+-]?((" + NUM + NUM + "*.?" + NUM + "*)|(." + NUM
        + NUM + "*))" + EXPONENT + "?)";

static String S_COMMA_S = "(( )*,( )*)";

static String NUM_DATA = "(" + NUMBER + "(" + S_COMMA_S + NUMBER + ")*)";
```

With how NUM_DATA is defined a possible match would be "123, 456"
As far as my understanding goes, any list of numbers ending with a number and not a comma should be valid. However, according to the following test method, it matches a number list ending in a comma

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(NUM_DATA);
        String s = "123";
        System.out.println(s.matches(NUM_DATA));
        s = "123, 456";
        System.out.println(s.matches(NUM_DATA));
        s = "123, 456,";//HANGING COMMA, SHOULD NOT MATCH
        System.out.println(s.matches(NUM_DATA));
}
```

Which results in the following output:

```
(([+-]?(([0-9][0-9]*.?[0-9]*)|(.[0-9][0-9]*))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]([0-9]([0-9])?)?)?)((( )*,( )*)([+-]?(([0-9][0-9]*.?[0-9]*)|(.[0-9][0-9]*))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]([0-9]([0-9])?)?)?))*)
true
true
true
```

Where are my assumptions going wrong? Or is this behavior incorrect?

EDIT: I suppose I should post the behavior I am expecting

```
Matches: (Any list of comma separated numbers, including one number)
    1.222
    1.222, 324.4
    2.51e123, 3e2
    -.123e-12, 32.1231, 1e1, .111, -1e-1
Non-Matches:
    123.321,
    ,
    , 123.321
```

Comment: If you write your requirements clearly with examples of what should and what shouldn't match then your regex can be simplified.

Comment: I am not attempting to simplify the Regex because I am writing it to match a specification. To show that each of the fields match the specification I use the same format to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your NUMBER regex you have a `.` which matches any character, also a comma in the end, you need to escape it `\.`, but in Java Strings `\` has to be escaped, so it is `"\\."` in a String.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now :) Still learning Regex's so sorry if my problem seemed idiotic.

Comment: @SpencasaurusRex you're welcome, thanks for accepting. It is no problem and it's better to ask if you aren't sure, because although regex are very useful they are not suitable for all tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex can be refactored to a shorter:

```
^([+-]?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?)(?: *, *([+-]?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?))*$
```

This will still meet your requirements as you can see in this:

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT1sI1/1)

You will get all your numbers in matched groups.

I recommend you to use this regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher` API to avoid compiling this long regex again & again in `String#matches`.

Comment: I was actually avoiding refactoring it in order to match another specification :P Though thanks for the tip about the Pattern and Matcher :)